# Ubuntu 18.04 from VirtualBox sometimes has small window

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox

I'm using VirtualBox 6.1.8 on Windows 10. I've installed an Ubuntu 18.04 image provided by my company.  This installation includes the Guest Additions package.  Most of the time, the VM starts up perfectly fine, showing a fullscreen window, allowing cut/paste between the VM and host, and shared folders are mounted.

However, quite often when I start up the VM, I get a small window that looks like before I installed Guest Additions.  However, cut/paste between host/VM still works, and I still have shared folders.  When this happens, I restart the VM, and it almost always starts up fine on the second try.

I had a feeling that this is some sort of race condition, so I thought perhaps not logging in as quickly as I usually do might help.  I used to have it set to auto-login, and it seemed like this happened more often with that.  I now wait until the login page appears, and I don't immediately sign in.  It's possible this helps, but this morning it didn't.  I still got the small window, then I restarted, and after logging in again, I got a large window again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **VirtualBox** --> **Ubuntu 18.04** --> **Settings** --> **Display** --> **Graphics Controller** is set as default **VMSVGA**, change it to **VBoxSVGA**

Comment: Ok, well, that's curious.  VboxVGA was the old setting, and now VirtualBox marks that as an "Invalid Setting" and recommends "VMSVGA".  I need some more information here.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, change it to VboxSVGA.. I have multiple Virtual Machines and all of them have different Graphics Controller, for example Linux Mint 20 VM uses VBoxVGA and Ubuntu 20.04 uses VBoxSVGA as Graphics Controller.. Even if it shows invalid settings at the bottom it's going to work..

Comment: Do you happen to have a link to documentation that makes this certain?  I did verify that VBoxSVGA appears to work, and it even makes the login screen fullscreen (VMSVGA would make the login screen small, and the desktop fullscreen, if possible). I'd also like to understand why VirtualBox seems to think this is the wrong setting.

Comment: One of our engineers seems to think that it's the upgrade to VirtualBox 6.1.x that supposedly requires the VMSVGA adapter. You have specifically said that Ubuntu 20.04 "uses" VBoxSVGA.  Perhaps 18.04 is "on the fence" as it were. It seems like we have conflicting requirements here.

Comment: I have the same opinion.. Before version 6 there was no need to change the Graphics Controller, just installing the Guest Additions and everything was working properly. I dont have any documentation, I tried just multiple times changing the Settings..and if this solved your problem then you can accept it as a solution, otherwise maybe someone else can help you to find a solution...

Comment: I just need more verification. That engineer seems to think that VBoxSVGA on 18.04 will cause crashes on login. I'm waiting for him to reply to my request for more information. I haven't seen that happen. I'm wondering whether it's actually on 20.04 that this happens, not 18.04. At this point, I think I'll just accept this answer.